# How to create hints in the textview edit box that go away when textview has focus?

Tags: android, textview, type-hinting

How do I do this? 
For example, when I create a question on stackoverflow, the Title text field has this in the edit TextView box:

> what's your programming question? be specific.

As soon as you tab into it, or start typing it goes away.
How do you accomplish this for the android?
thanks,

Comment: SO should have done the same thing for search box too :P

Answer (score 9):

In the Activity XML specify

> android:hint="Your Message"

under TextView. There is no need to override method onClick

Alternatively, you can use setHint() in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a default value (your hint) and override the onclick method (make a new class that extends TextView).
Yous check if the text displayed is the initial one and only reset the textfield if it still is.

Answer (score 0):

with proper option:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29